# How do I exclude '@2x.png' files from grunt-contrib-packer

Tags: gruntjs

How do I exclude files from `grunt-contrib-packer`, for example I want to make a sprite sheet of 1x graphics and @2x graphics.

```
       spritepacker: {
            sprites: {
                options: {
                  template: 'css/sprites.css.tpl',
                  destCss: 'css/sprites.css',
                  baseUrl: '/img/'
                },
                files: {
                  'img/sprites/sprites.png': ['img/sprites/*.png']
                }
            },
            sprites_2x: {
                options: {
                  template: 'css/sprites.css.tpl',
                  destCss: 'css/sprites@2x.css',
                  baseUrl: '/img/'
                },
                files: {
                  'img/sprites/sprites@2x.png': ['img/sprites/*@2x.png']
                }
            }
        }
```

As you can see the first rule will select all of the .png images, how can I write that rule to exclude @2x.png files?  I tried `*!(@2x).png` and this did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `*!(@2x).png`, add the exclusion mark to the beginning of the line

```
files: {
    'img/sprites/sprites.png': [
        'img/sprites/*.png', 
        '!img/sprites/*@2x.png'
    ]
}
```

See [Globbing patterns](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns)

> `!` at the beginning of a pattern will negate the match